# Jax-rs unmarshal json - custom type

Tags: json, jersey, adapter, jax-rs, unmarshalling

Using jax-rs, I'm not sure how to manually unmarshal JSON into my custom Java objects.

From my browser I'm sending a simple put request with the following JSON:

```
{"myDate":{"dayOfMonth":23, "monthOfYear":7, "year":2011}}
```

On the server I have a BlahResource which consumes this JSON and prints out the Java object properties:

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
@Path("/blah")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public class BlahResource {

    @PUT
    public String putBlah(Blah blah) {
        System.out.println("Value: " + blah.getMyDate().getMonthOfYear() + "/" + blah.getMyDate().getDayOfMonth() + "/" + blah.getMyDate().getYear());
        return "{}";
    }
}
```

Here's the source code for Blah:

```
public class Blah {

    private LocalDate myDate;

    public Blah()
    {
    }

    public void setMyDate(LocalDate myDate)
    {
        this.myDate = myDate;
    }

    public LocalDate getMyDate()
    {
        return myDate;
    }
}
```

The problem is Blah.myDate is a Joda-time LocalDate class which does not have setters for dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, and year.  So for instance, when I run this the following exception is thrown:

```
Jul 10, 2011 8:40:33 AM
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException

SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not
 be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
 Unrecognized field "dayOfMonth"
```

This makes perfect sense to me.  The problem is I have no idea how to write some sort of adapter so that whenever the type LocalDate is encountered, my adapter class is used to convert the JSON into a LocalDate.

Ideally, I want to do something like this:

```
public class LocalDateAdapter {
    public LocalDate convert(String json)
    {
        int dayOfMonth = (Integer)SomeJsonUtility.extract("dayOfMonth");
        int year = (Integer)SomeJsonUtility.extract("year");
        int monthOfYear = (Integer)SomeJsonUtility.extract("monthOfYear");
        return new LocalDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

I've now tried two methods, neither seem to be working.

1) Using ObjectMapper

It seems all I need to do is get a handle on the ObjectMapper and add a deserializer.  So I created this provider.  To my surprise, I named my dserializer: LocalDateDeserializer and when I had eclipse auto-fix imports I was shocked to see that Jackson already provides an extension for Joda.  When I start the server, it finds the provider, but otherwise it seems this code is never invoked.

```
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.codehaus.jackson.Version;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers.LocalDateDeserializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.module.SimpleModule;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule testModule = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null))
                     .addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer());
                 mapper.registerModule(testModule);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

---

2) The second method I tried is to specify a @JsonDeserialize annotation directly on the field.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
private LocalDate myDate;
```

This also didn't seem to be invoked.

```
public class CustomDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        return new LocalDate(2008, 2, 5);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what to do. This seems like a very basic problem.

### UPDATE 2

I'm considering dropping Jackson for using deserialization (even though it works fairly well with Jersey).

I was already using flexjson for serialization, and it seems flexjson is just as simple for deserialization.  All these other libraries have some much abstraction and unnecessary complexity.

In Flexjson, I just had to implement ObjectFactory:

```
class LocalDateTransformer implements ObjectFactory {

    @Override
    public Object instantiate(ObjectBinder context, Object value, Type targetType, Class targetClass)
    {
        HashMap map = (HashMap)value;
        int year = (Integer)map.get("year");
        int monthOfYear = (Integer)map.get("monthOfYear");
        int dayOfMonth = (Integer)map.get("dayOfMonth");
        return new LocalDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

It looks surprisingly like the "adapter" class I originally posted!  And my resource method now becomes:

```
@PUT
public String putBlah(String blahStr) {
    Blah blah = new JSONDeserializer<Blah>().use(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateTransformer()).deserialize(blahStr, Blah.class);
}
```

Comment: SimpleModule.addDeserializer only seems to work at the bean level.  So I can do something like this: SimpleMoule.addDeserializer(Blah.class, new BlahDeserializer()) but that's definitely not what I want.  I want the serializer to work at the field level so for any class if it finds a certain .class it will deserialize it using a custom deserializer.

Comment: Why don't you decorate your `Blah` with JAXB annotations and see what exactly Jersey prints out as JSON? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593543/print-jersey-json-in-unit-testing